# Webdriver firefox-bin uses excessive amount of CPU

Tags: java, firefox, cpu, webdriver, ubuntu-9.10

I am running a single test (FirefoxDriveR)which visits all links on a given domain.

OS: Ubuntu 9.10
Memory: 4GB
HD: 500GB
10 mbp/s line

Observing the following via command `TOP`

```
11001 hudson    20   0  508m 108m  28m S   64  2.8   2:31.58 firefox-bin
10937 hudson    20   0 1277m  73m 9772 S    6  1.8   0:21.93 java
10929 hudson    20   0 43820  10m 3440 S    3  0.3   0:06.25 Xvnc
```

64% CPU Consumption via firefox-bin. Anyway I can reduce this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a 3Ghz machine, I see firefox using in the range from 25-40% CPU when running at full blast through a site. Remember that firefox is effectively an execution environment for code. So page efficiency corrolates to CPU usage on the host.

Standard tricks for optimizing javascript, css and page rendering apply here, this is not about webdriver as such, although you can expect a baseline for reasonably efficient pages around 30%

Comment: is there anyway I can run more parallel firefox driver sessions ? If firefox-bin eats that much cpu at any given time, how can I achieve more firefoxdriver sessions being run simultaneously ? I would like to achieve something like 5 to 10 firefox-bin and respective webdriver tests being run on a single box.

Comment: can you recommend a box ? I'm surprised you can run 25 firefox-bin without any problems !

Comment: i980X w/32 GB ram should do fine. I love it ;)